# Remove unwanted latex code from final document.

Tags: latex, knitr, r-markdown

I made a file in rmarkdown to submit to a journal, but when I went to actually upload the file, they want raw latex. Okay, part of my YAML is.

```
output: 
   pdf_document:
     keep_tex: true
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{color}
  - \usepackage{lineno}
     - \linenumbers
```

The preview of the document looks great, except it starts out like this (just text not, in code format:

```
[]article lmodern amssymb,amsmath ifxetex,ifluatex fixltx2e =0 [T1]fontenc
[utf8]inputenc fontspec Ligatures=TeX,Scale=MatchLowercase upquote microtype
[protrusion]basicmath [margin=1in]geometry hyperref graphicx,grffile parskip
titling
color lineno
```

followed by everything I want. Where do I look to get rid of this?

Comment: Something has messed up the start of your .tex file, so you should look there.  If you want more specific help, you'll have to post a short reproducible example.

Comment: I'm not sure this question will be useful to many, but I did figure it out. I was being asked to paste latex into a web form. I pasted everything, but the requesters had their own formatting/packages in the background. So I pasted just my text and it all worked out.